# Hand Gesture using Moments Opencv

Tags: opencv, feature-extraction

I am doing a gesture recognition to voice using openCV , I am using moments to find orientation of hand , however the result of computing orientation arent meaningful enough for me , so i need help understanding them . I also dont know how should i go on after 
finding the orientation angle o the image .

### This Part finds orientation angle :

```
    cvMoments( tempDB, &moments, 1 );   

u11=cvGetCentralMoment( &moments, 1,1 ); 
u20=cvGetCentralMoment( &moments, 2,0 ); 
u02=cvGetCentralMoment( &moments, 0,2 ); 
cout<<moments.m00<<"moo"<<endl;
cout<<moments.m11<<"m11"<<endl;
cout<<moments.m02<<"m02"<<endl;
cout<<moments.m20<<"m21"<<endl;
/////////////////////////////////////// EQ 1 //////////////////////////////////////////////////
theta=2*u11/(u20-u02); 

cout <<" The ANGLE theta in radians  = " <<theta <<endl; 
theta = 180*theta/pi;
cout <<" The ANGLE theta in degree  = " <<theta <<endl; 

if ((theta >=0) & (theta <=45)) {
//Page 65of 83 
theta2 = 0.5*atan(2*u11/(u20-u02));
cout<<"1"<<endl;
cout<<theta2<<"theta2 in radians in 1st cond"<<endl;
}
else {
if ((theta > -45) & (theta < 0)) {
    cout<<"2"<<endl;
    theta2 =  0.5*atan(2*u11/(u20-u02));
cout<<theta2<<"theta2 in radians in 2nd cond"<<endl;
}
else{ 
    if ((theta > 45) & (theta < 90)) {
    cout<<"3"<<endl;
    theta2 =  0.5*atan(2*u11/(u20-u02)) +( pi/2);
cout<<theta2<<"theta2 in radians in 3nd cond"<<endl;
} else {
    if ((theta > -90) & (theta < -45)) {
    cout<<"4"<<endl;
    theta2 =  0.5*atan(2*u11/(u20-u02)) -( pi/2);
cout<<theta2<<"theta2 in radians in 4nd cond"<<endl;
    } else  { cout << " u didnt handle this condition "<<endl; } 

 }

}

}
theta2 = 180*theta2/pi;
cout <<"angle theta2 of secnod image in degrees = " <<theta2 <<endl; 
cout <<"a b4 while loop = " <<a<<endl; 


Results : 
--------

widthis159heght is 189
60980 Non Zero Pixels in TEST
done first rotation

Angle of first image 0
60980 moo
1.93244e+009 m11
3.70591e+009 m02
2.11377e+009 m21
 The ANGLE theta in radians  = 1.12166
 The ANGLE theta in degree  = 64.2666
3
1.99214theta2 in radians in 3rd cond
angle theta2 of secnod image in degrees = 114.141
a b4 while loop = 0
```

---

![I got these equation from here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwXh2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the issues I see:

```
    cvMoments( tempDB, &moments, 1 );   

u11=cvGetCentralMoment( &moments, 1,1 ); 
u20=cvGetCentralMoment( &moments, 2,0 ); 
u02=cvGetCentralMoment( &moments, 0,2 ); 
cout<<moments.m00<<"moo"<<endl;
cout<<moments.m11<<"m11"<<endl;
cout<<moments.m02<<"m02"<<endl;
cout<<moments.m20<<"m21"<<endl;
/////////////////////////////////////// EQ 1 //////////////////////////////////////////////////
theta=2*u11/(u20-u02); 

cout <<" The ANGLE theta in radians  = " <<theta <<endl; 
theta = 180*theta/pi;
cout <<" The ANGLE theta in degree  = " <<theta <<endl; 

if ((theta >=0) && (theta <=45)) /*single & is binary (each bit individually) instead of the whole thing*/ {
//Page 65of 83 
theta2 = 0.5*atan(2*u11/(u20-u02));
cout<<"1"<<endl;
cout<<theta2<<"theta2 in radians in 1st cond"<<endl;
}
else {
if ((theta > -45) && (theta < 0)) /*same issue here*/ {
    cout<<"2"<<endl;
    theta2 =  0.5*atan(2*u11/(u20-u02));
cout<<theta2<<"theta2 in radians in 2nd cond"<<endl;
}
else{ 
    if ((theta > 45) && (theta < 90)) /*the brace placement sucks, but use && instead of &*/{ 
    cout<<"3"<<endl;
    theta2 =  0.5*atan(2*u11/(u20-u02)) +( pi/2);
cout<<theta2<<"theta2 in radians in 3nd cond"<<endl;
} else {
    if ((theta > -90) && (theta < -45)) {
    cout<<"4"<<endl;
    theta2 =  0.5*atan(2*u11/(u20-u02)) -( pi/2);
cout<<theta2<<"theta2 in radians in 4nd cond"<<endl;
    } else  { cout << " u didnt handle this condition "<<endl; } 

 }

}

}
theta2 = 180*theta2/pi;
cout <<"angle theta2 of secnod image in degrees = " <<theta2 <<endl; 
cout <<"a b4 while loop = " <<a<<endl;
```

You were using & instead of &&, essentially masking the bits. the only way that would ever be false is if theta was the exact binary opposite of theta (impossible). the first if is always true.

Comment: i used && like u mentioned and the result were exactly the same , can you clarify more? thanks .

Comment: oh! my bad, its incorrect logic... let me swap the &&'s to ||'s

Comment: I lied...its correct as is. there must be another problem